# Query to show future recurring revenue

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, coldfusion, jqplot

I'm working in ColdFusion and SQL Server and trying to output some information using jqPlot. The part I'm struggling with is the SQL query.

I have a DB that has a table of recurring fee's that our subscribers charge their clients.
They're like accounts receivables that will auto charge on their respective future dates/intervals. (every 1(2,3,4,etc) day, week, month, quarter, year).

I'm trying to build a bar chart that will show me totals for the current day, the next 7 days, the next 30 days, 90 days, and the next 365 days) based on the pre-existing data.

The table contains:

- Date Completed = the day the fee was initially setup.
- Rate = the cost of the fee.
- Next Billing Date = The next day the fee will convert to a line item (updated to new date each conversion)
- Frequency Unit = d,ww,m,q,yyyy
- Frequency Duration = 1,2,3,4, etc

The last 2 determine what the next billing date will be upon conversion.
It also has a Subscriber ID and a Client ID to keep track of who it's for. (That I have worked out)

Can someone please help out with how I might do this using jqPlot? (*I've got the javascript worked out on how to display the graph, it's the query that has me stumped*)

Thank you very much in advance.

Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the query, which is what you said was causing you difficulty, I would try something like this:

```
<cfset DaysAhead = "7,30,365">
<cfset Today = CreateDate(year(now()), month(now()), day(now()))>

<cfquery>
select 'today' period, sum(rate) amount
from yourtable
where BillingDate >= <cfqueryparam value = "#Today#">
and BillingDate < DateAdd(day, 1, <cfqueryparam value = "#Today#">)

<cfloop list = "#DaysAhead#" index = ThisManyDays>
union
select '#ThisManyDays# ahead' period, , sum(rate) amount
from yourtable
where BillingDate >= <cfqueryparam value = "#Today#">
and BillingDate < DateAdd(day, #ThisManyDays# + 1, <cfqueryparam value = "#Today#">)

</cfloop>
```